# Combining args in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a command using a game framework which doesn't support the use of quotes to create arguments with spaces.
I tried to merge every separate argument after the first to make a final string to use but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong:

```
case "add":
    client.SendToClient(PluginUtils.CreateNotification(client.ObjectId, 8453888, "Logged to console"));
    string FullArgs = "";
    for (int i = 1; i == args.Length; i++ )
    {
        FullArgs = FullArgs + args[i];
    }
    Console.WriteLine("[Anti-Spam] " + FullArgs + " added to filter list");
    break;
```

To clarify I'm using array index 1 to begin with because 0 is already part of the command, so anything 1 and beyond I would like to combine into a string.
I'm not getting any errors and just getting a blank output, can anyone please help or even suggest a better way? Greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Are you sure args[] exists ?

Comment: This looks like it should work, step through the code and see what is happening in the loop.

Comment: @HynekBernard Yeah absolutely, the code wouldn't get that far without args[0]

Comment: The loop condition should use the `<` operator instead of `==`. It tests if the loop should keep going, not when it should stop.

Comment: [System.Environment.CommandLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.commandline) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guessing it should be:

```
for (int i = 1; i < args.Length; i++ )
{
  FullArgs = FullArgs + args[i];
}
```

If `args.length` is > 1, it will never populate `FullArgs`

Comment: Wow, can't believe how stupid an error that was, I just assumed == would make it go from 1 to the end. Thanks so much for your input :)